# Why does IE9 render fonts in a bloated and blurry manner?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, fonts, rendering

I am getting an issue with IE9 rendering in a bloated and blurry manor. The font style is Arial. The way it looks in ie9 is like this:

[image: ie9 blurry]

Where as in other browsers it looks like this:

[image: same font in chrome]

I have changed the ie9 properties, but nothing has worked. I do not believe it to be a CSS issue, and I am at my means end trying to figure this out. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the CSS filter property:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod="auto expand");
```

solution:

`filter:none;`

Answer (score 0):

Older IEs don't render semi-bold or many numeric `font-weight` properly

try:

```
font-weight: normal;

//or if the font has bold type
font-weight: bold;
```

Also try some different fonts